# Least square block matrix problem

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, least-squares

Let $A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    R & w\\
    0 & v \\
    \end{bmatrix}$
and $b =
\begin{bmatrix}
    c\\
    d\\
    \end{bmatrix}$,

where $R$ is a $k × k$ block $c,w ∈ R^k, v, d ∈ R^{m−k},$ and the zero is a block of appropriate dimension.
If $A ∈ R^{m×(k+1)}$ has full column rank, then show that$$min_x ||Ax-b||_2^2 = ||d||_2^2 - (\frac{v^Td}{||v||_2})^2$$

Comment: $Ax - b$ is a column-vector, so that first norm should be $\|\cdot\|_2$ instead of $\|\cdot\|_F$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If we write $x = (\tilde x,\alpha)$ where $\tilde x \in \Bbb R^k$ and $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, then we have
$$
\|Ax - b\|_2^2 = \|R\tilde x - (c - \alpha w)\|_2^2 + \|\alpha v - d\|_2^2.
$$
Note also that because $R$ is square with linearly independent columns, it is invertible.

Comment: Could you please provide any further help ? What after this how do we proceed ?

Comment: Minimize the second term noting that for any $\alpha,c,w$, we can find a $\tilde x$ such that the first term is zero.

Comment: Thank you! I got it.